# In MVP Architecture, which layer should check the content of the fields?

Tags: architecture, mvp

My presentation has an Array which contain field names and their values.
More precisely, each value is an object (like "User" for example) of the Model.

I would like to know if the presentation itself should perform checking on the content of those fields or should it be done by a contained class?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217752/in-mvp-where-to-write-validations

Answer (score 2):

Depend of a lot of points.

In a conventional way, the presentation layer should care about how the data is presented on the `UI` to final users. Just it. We usually have what we call as `business layer` (BL) and it give some treatments on the data, which has retrieved from the `data access layer` (DAL) before going to the presentation layer (UI).

Said that, it is not a rule you must follow, but it is a best pratice of the software architecturing;

Comment: So if I understand, BL and DAL are part of the Model right?

Comment: They are part of the architecture. The model is about your domain (entities).

Comment: Thanks, I think I might have misunderstood and made a bad mix of all this ( MVP / business logic, etc.) May I ask you a good website that explain all of this ? I took a look on Martin Fowler's Website already but maybe there are other good sources ?

Comment: I enjoy `domain driven-design` approach. There is a book from Eric Evans which present how to deal with it. Martin Fowler's website is a good one as well.

Comment: @Freddykong: No, BL *is* the Model. The business layer defines the domain model.  MVP is not exactly an architecture, it's more of an architectural pattern (some would even call it a design pattern) concerned with decoupling the view(s) from the (domain) model. The DAL is *not* a part of MVP - it's on the "other side" of the BL (that is, it usually exists in the same application, but is outside the scope of the MVP architectural pattern).

Comment: Also, in MVVM (a variant of the Presentation Model pattern as described by Fowler), there's something called ViewModel - but this is not the same as the (domain) Model described above. A ViewModel is not a part of the domain (BL), but is a part of the presentation - it represents and describes the behavior of the view (and some binding between the controls and the view model is usually involved). Note that you still have a (domain) model in MVVM (it's just not in the name).